# Typescript Optional Property Access

Tags: typescript

In the expression:

document.getElementById('text-elementName')?.style.display = "block";

I'm getting the warning: *The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property *

What is the best practice for correcting this?

thanks!